# Alternative of CreateDefaultBuilder in .NET 6 core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I don't want to use CreateDefaultBuilder and ConfigureWebHostDefaults in Program.cs file. Both of these functions make certain assumptions, that I am not comfortable with, also I don't want to rely on ASP.net defaults. I want to setup builder myself but don't know how to do that

I want to replace following code with my own builder

```
var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
       .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
       {
           builder.Sources.Clear();
           ...
       })
       .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
       {
           ...
       })
       .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
        services.Configure<...>(
            context.Configuration.GetSection("...")))
    .Build();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an instance of [`HostBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostbuilder) directly:

```cs
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .Build();
```

`HostBuilder` has a number of useful methods, such as [`ConfigureServices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostbuilder.configureservices?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#microsoft-extensions-hosting-hostbuilder-configureservices(system-action((microsoft-extensions-hosting-hostbuildercontext-microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection)))), [`ConfigureAppConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostbuilder.configureappconfiguration?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0), etc:

```cs
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
    {
        // ...
    })
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        // ...
    })
    .Build();
```

To configure the `WebHost`, without the defaults, use [`ConfigureWebHost`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.generichostwebhostbuilderextensions.configurewebhost?view=aspnetcore-7.0):

```cs
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureWebHost(webHostBuilder =>
    {
            
    })
    .Build();
```